# Dart How do I create a modal page?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, dart

I have created my first web application and have .html, .dart, and .css files.  I want to create a modal page that will a bit smaller than my page and be centered on it.  I don't really want any visible borders.  The function of this page is to allow the user to display, using clickable elements, 'Help' and 'About' pages and a page that allow the user to see a list of the data files that have been collected.

I've found a couple of examples of modal pages but they are old.  One appears to be easy to understand but the Dart editor flags a couple of errors and has a line that I don't understand at the head of the .dart file.

```
#import('dart:html'); // OK just remove the '#"

#resource('modal.css'); // ???
```

This example is in a blog [DartBlog](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/02/modal-dialog-in-dart.html) that does not appear to be active and did not allow me to leave a comment.

I would appreciate an help understanding the example or pointing me to working examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This import statement is outdated Dart syntax.

use instead

```dart
import 'dart:html';
```

I never saw the `#resource` thing and I'm sure this is not available anymore as well.

You can either put a style tag to your HTML file like

```dart
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
.black_overlay{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 z-index:1001;
 -moz-opacity: 0.8;
 opacity:.80;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index:1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

or put the CSS content in a file like `styles.css` and import it to your HTML

```dart
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to update the code to current syntax (not tested though) and I added some comments

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  //setup the screen elements...
  ButtonElement button = new ButtonElement();
  button.text = "click me";
  //add an event handler
  button.onclick.listen((event) {
    ModalDialog dialog = new ModalDialog("This is a <strong>message</strong>
with html formatting");
    dialog.show();
  });
  //add the button to the screen
  document.body.append(button);

  //add the modal dialog stylesheet
  document.head.append(getStylesheet()); 

}

/**
* Our modal dialog class
*/
class ModalDialog {
  final DivElement _content;
  final DivElement _blackOverlay;
  final ButtonElement _button;

  //Constructor
  ModalDialog(String message) :
    //constructor pre-init
    _content = new DivElement(),
    _blackOverlay = new DivElement(),
    _button = new ButtonElement()
  {
    //constructor body
    _content.id = "modalContent";
    _content.classes.add("white_content");  //set the class for CSS
    _blackOverlay.id = "modalOverlay";
    _blackOverlay.classes.add("black_overlay"); //set the class for CSS

    //Our message will go inside this span
    SpanElement span = new SpanElement();
    span.innerHTML = message;
    _content.append(span);

    //This is the button that will "clear" the dialog
    _button.text = "Ok";
    _button.onClick.listen((event) {
      hide();
    });

    _content.append(_button);
  }

  //remove the modal dialog div's from the dom.
  hide() {
    //find the element and remove it.
    //there is no list.remove(x) statement at present,
    // so we have to do it manually. - UPDATE: now there is
    _content.remove();
    _blackOverlay.remove();
  }

  //add the modal dialog div's to the dom
  show() {
    document.body.append(_content);
    document.body.append(_blackOverlay);
  }
}

/**
* Utility method to get a stylesheet object
*/
getStylesheet() {
  LinkElement styleSheet = new LinkElement(); // maybe 
  styleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
  styleSheet.type="text/css";
  styleSheet.href="modal.css"; // UPDATE: you don't need to add your CSS to your HTML as shown above because it's done in this code
  return styleSheet;
}
```

Comment: The compiler complained a bit but I was able to work that out and after one other fix got it to work.  Now to integrate it with my application.  Thanks from a Dart/HTML novice for all your work.

Comment: One problem left. The editor compiler says that the `document.body.remove(_content);` statements don't take arguments.  If the argument is removed then **everything** is removed when the button is clicked.

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake. Just change it to `_content.remove();`

Comment: IIRC when I tried that using auto complete .remove() didn't show up ...  Works like a charm now.  Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!
If its a ButtonElement or similar it should list `.remove()`. If you get it passed in like in an event handler casting to `HtmlElement` improves the autocomplete experience `clickHandler(Event e) { (e.target as HtmlElement).remove();}`
Some methods/getters return the more generic `Node` type which has much less functionality.